# How do I install uuid boost library?

Tags: gcc, boost, uuid

I followed many tutorials to get boost installed, firstyly I downloaded boost and added path with:

```
path=%path%;
c:\program files (x86)\code block\mingw\bin
```

secondly I ran

```
bootstrap.bat gcc
```

and then

```
b2 toolset=gcc
```

but there is no such lib installed as UUID which I really need to my project. Is there any way to make it happen as I haven't found any specific help among all those topics and I'm getting really confused. I'm working on win10 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read documentation?
Boost UUID library is header-only library. See [Configuration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html#Configuration):

> The library does not require building or any special configuration to be used.

So you have to download boost library and unpack it to some place in your disk (for example to c:\boost). Path to boost library will be c:\boost\boost_1_62_0. Then you have to specify the compiler the place where the boost library is located. It is compiler or IDE specific way. But the common way is to use "Additional Include Directories" option of compiler. It is -I for GCC and /I for MS VC++. Last step is to write include directive in your c++ code. For example:

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
```

For code example see [Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html#Examples) and files in  boost/libs/uuid/test/ folder